# Hibernate HQL Join many-to-many not work anymore since version 5.2?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Since I upgraded Hibernate from 5.1 to 5.2.x the following named query not work anymore, please some help?

```
FROM      MemberDefault member
JOIN      member.helpers hlp
WHERE     hlp.helper = :helperId
```

It concerns 2 tables:
1) Member
2) Helpers: many-to-many that has two foreign key relations to the Member table concerning the Helper and the Member being helped.

The hibernate config snippet:

```
        <composite-element class="HelperDefault">
            <parent name="helperClient" />

            <many-to-one name="helper" column="idHlpMember" class="MemberDefault" not-null="true" cascade="none"/>
        </composite-element>
    </set>
```

The code that not works anymore in hibernate 5.2:

```
Query<Member> query = getPersister().getNamedQuery(Member.class, getQueries().findMembersByTheirHelper());
List<Member> members = query.setParameter("helperId", helperId).getResultList();
```

The exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.String] expected instance/subclass of [MemberDefault]
```

I then changed the last line in the named query to:
    WHERE     hlp.helper.id = :helperId

I realise that this is how it should be in the first place, and I was doing it wrong.
And I do get the exception:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: helper.id of: MemberDefault
```

Why is it using the MemberDefault instance to look up the property "helper.id" and not the HelperDefault instance? Is this a bug?

The workaround that I found:
I changed the named query back to the original one with the last line like:

```
WHERE     hlp.helper = :helperId
```

And specified the object MemberDefault as parameter helperId instead of the id (String), so the code looks like:

```
         Member helper = findMemberById(helperId);
        Query<Member> query = getPersister().getNamedQuery(Member.class, getQueries().findTaxersByTheirHelper());
List<Member> members = query.setParameter(getQueryParams().helperId(), helper).getResultList();
```

Any idea how this could/should work with the helperId as String ? (like it was working before 5.2)

Comment: What I see is that you were always doing it wrong and your 'workaround' is actually as it always should have been; at least according to the query. Apparently Hibernate prior to version 5.2 was more forgiving. The direct query on ID should also work, but without seeing the entity classes involved its impossible to tell what might be wrong such that the ID property can't be resolved.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was doing it wrong, but like you mentioned, the helper.id option should work as well, but how? What do you need to see of the entities? I don't mind putting them here, but not sure it helps and which part of the entity without over-bloating this issue with code. I think you can retrieve all the entity info from the hibernate config (I don't use hibernate annotations in the entities)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding an extra JOIN to the HSQL:

```
SELECT    member
FROM      MemberDefault member
JOIN      member.helpers helpers
JOIN      helpers.helper hlp
WHERE     hlp.id = :helperId
```

Note: I understand it, as this is how I would do it in native sql, however before Hibernate 5.2 (maybe already earlier), this wasn't needed!